# Positive definite matrix to be cancalled

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

From $ax\geq 0$ for $a>0$, we have $x\geq 0$. So I suggest that if $Ax\geq 0$ for $A$ positive definite matrix, $x$ a column vector, $0$ is the column vector with $0$ as elements, then $x\geq 0$, that is, the coordinate of $x$ is greater than $0$.

However, I could not prove it...

Comment: Dose $A$ fixed or arbitrary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive definiteness is rather a spectral property than a "component-wise" one.
A randomly generated example shows that the statement is not true:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 \\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix},
x=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\3\end{bmatrix},
Ax=\begin{bmatrix}7\\12\end{bmatrix}.
$$

This is true for [M-matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix), which in the symmetric case happen to be positive definite. Not all positive definite matrices are M-matrices though.

Answer (score 2):

If $Ax\geq0$ for arbitrary positive definite matrix $A$, then the conclusion is right just by take $A=I$.
If $Ax\geq0$ for a fixed positive definite matrix $A$, then 
$A=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
     1 & 1 \\
     1 & 4 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$
$x=\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     -1  \\
      1  \\
  \end{array}
\right)$
is a example show that the conclusion is not true.